# Assembly language translation to machine code (process in "RAM")

Tags: programming-languages, binary

How does a assembler (at very basic level) work in translation of Assembly language to machine code ? Just want to know that what is happening in RAM ?

[What my understanding is that when  when I type MOV A, B   : in RAM :'M' >> some bytes (ASCII CODE) in memory (RAM)in form of 0v and 5v (voltage may be different but you know what I mean) 'O' will be saved with same method & so V , A , "," , B .Now the programming software also have the part in RAM which we call "library" saved in 0s & 1s in the form of 0v /5v.So my question is that does "translation" mean that typed the 0s,1s of MOV A,B will be compared to saved 0s and 1s (library's)by logic ckt & then depending on the matching or mismatching of those 0s,1s will result in another 0s,1s (opcodes bits/bytes ,will be stored & later executed in RAM)?Am I right or is this a wrong way of thinking? ]

Comment: The matching process you describe is pretty obscure and miles away from what actually occurs.

Comment: Sir can you explain  me ? what happens "only in the RAM " with corresponding steps in the assembler all the way from typing my code to output of the code ? I am tired of searching my answer and feeling stupid now :(

Comment: and what about  things I wrote other than matching/mismatching thing ?

Comment: This seems very broad, especially as you're discussing things at the level of voltages of individual memory cells. You need to decide at what level you're thinking. You seem to be asking about at least three levels of architecture here: how does an assembler work (as a computer program, assuming that the computer "just works"), how do CPUs work (as logical devices without reference to a physical implementation) and how do CPUs and memories work as physical devices that manipulate voltages. Each single one of those is a very broad question on its own.

Comment: I suggest that you Google existing resources for these questions and ask more specific questions here when there are parts you don't understand.

Comment: I know this is a somewhat old question, but if you're still looking for more detail here, I wrote [an in-depth explanation of the inner workings of a typical assembler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227983/how-do-we-go-from-assembly-to-machine-codecode-generation/320297#320297) over on softwareengineering stack exchange a while ago that may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

In modern computers, *assemblers* do not deal directly with in-RAM machine code anymore. Their job is to translate the textual representation of the assembly language to opcode combinations, in a form that is not completely finished because exact addresses are not decided yet.

Both the tetx and its translation are stored in disk files, they only reside in RAM while translation takes place.

A next step is performed by another utility, the *linker*, which performs address assignments and creates another file, called the executable, and will also reside on disk.

When you want execution to take place, a third program called the *loader* will read the opcodes from disk and write them in RAM memory where it belongs. Then the loader will tell the operating system that a new task is ready for execution and eventually control will be passed to the program you have written and which is now loaded in RAM.

(This explanation is really simplified as there are many intervening steps and other goodies to consider.)